# State not being saved when submitting a react form

Tags: typescript

I currently have dynamic components rendered from the serverside and one of the components returned is the submit button.

I have some inputs on the page which are child components and actually set the right values on the page. However on submission the state defaults to the initial values.

Below is the parent component

```
<Component {...item }
                                                onStateChange={(childState: any) => handleChildStateChange(childState, elementId)}
                                                onValidationChange={setIsFormValid}
                                                onError={(errorState: boolean) => handleErrors(errorState, elementId)}
                                                isDisabled={() => hasErrors()}
                                               onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                                            />
```

So in my child component the submit button renders with the following code. (Note: i added even.preventdefault() to see if it stops the reset)

```
export const SubmitButton: React.FC = (props: LooseObject) => {

    const { content, elementId, onSubmit, isDisabled } = props

    const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        console.log("event", event);
        event.preventDefault();
        onSubmit();
    }

    return (
        <button
            id={elementId}
            type="submit"
            className="bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-700 text-white p-2 rounded-md mt-7 disabled:opacity-50"
            disabled={isDisabled()} // Disable button if form is invalid
            onSubmit={handleClick}
        >
            {content}
         </button>
    )
}
```

In my parent component i have the handleSubmit function as it needs the state set in the parent like so

```
 const handleSubmit = () => {
        //event.preventDefault();
        console.log("...parentState on submit", parentState);
}
```

if i put the event in the parent it states function is not found as even is undefined.

But the state resets as well on submission i.e. when i press the submit the parent state is set to the original values.

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: wasnt so sure from question about whats going on but maybe its just putting a get request and refreshing page so you can avoid that by adding type="button" to button. If not that maybe a simple link to playground could be useful to help

Comment: will try to get it on a playground

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that my child component had a useEffect on the values which reset them on submit hence the issue. Now has been resolved by removing useEffect from child component